# Bash script for Git & VSS interop

Tags: bash, git

I have been slowly evolving some code for Git and VSS interop based on a [quest I started a while ago](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/260718/how-best-can-i-use-git-when-my-employer-uses-vss/261218#261218)

And the code is now working, some parts have been updated without test (such as the init) and I am not 100% sure everything is doing what it should/is the best way and [some parts seem really round the houses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27061794/sourcesafe-add-files-into-specific-project-directories-via-command-line)!

Its certainly past the point where it needs some input.

The basic concept is

- "Pulling" from source safe is achieved by keeping a separate "vss_branch"
- - vss_branch is kept up to kept up to date with source safe via a full source safe get
- - master treats vss_branch as its "upstream/origin" so master pulls from vss_branch
- "Pushing" to source safe
- - is achieved by figuring out what is different between master and vss_branch
- - saving and then pushing to vss_branch
- - then I go through all the modified/deleted/added files, and applying the appropriate operation e.g. checking them out and checking them in

*The code is currently used in the context of git, vss, beyondcompare and trackgear*

**I am keeping an up to date version** [here](https://github.com/chrispepper1989/GitVssInterop):

Code at time of question:

```bash
#--useful aliases
alias gitremove="git ls-files --deleted -z | xargs -0 git rm"
alias bcompare="START / \"C:\Program Files (x86)\Beyond Compare 3\BCompare.exe\""
alias initgitss=InitGitAndSourceSafeProject
alias ssclone="ss get "$CURRENT_SOURCE_SAFE_PROJECT" -W -R -Q -Y$SSNAME -I-N"
alias ssdiff="ss Diff -Y$SSNAME"    

#----These Need Setting:
##Your source safe project
CURRENT_SOURCE_SAFE_PROJECT=
##You Working directory 
CURRENT_PROJ_DIR=

#--For Source Safe Comments
ACTIVE_TRACK_REF=
PROJECT_NAME=

##Your BeyondCompare Session
#its better to create a beyond compare session so you can set it up how you like
BEYOND_COMPARE_SESSION=

#----SysVars
REF_APPEND="_REF"


#--variable set up helper 
sset()
{
    if [ $# -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo "No arguments supplied, please supply the SS project name"
    fi

    CURRENT_SOURCE_SAFE_PROJECT=$1
    CURRENT_PROJ_DIR=$(pwd)
}

#--create a git project from a VSS project and set everything up ---#
InitGitAndSourceSafeProject()
{

    if [ -z ${CURRENT_SOURCE_SAFE_PROJECT+x} ]; 
        then echo "CURRENT_SOURCE_SAFE_PROJECT is unset"; 
        exit;
    fi

    git init

    #get all the SS sourcecode
    echo "Switching to $CURRENT_SOURCE_SAFE_PROJECT"
    ss cp $CURRENT_SOURCE_SAFE_PROJECT

    ssclone

    git add --all
    git commit -m "Initial Source Safe Clone"
    #create fake upstream
    git checkout -b vss_branch
    #create a dev branch
    git checkout -b dev
    git checkout master
    #set master to treat "vss_branch" as upstream
    git branch --set-upstream-to vss_branch
    SynchMasterToSS

}


#---reset to current project---#
sreset()
{
    echo "Make sure we are in the correct source safe project"
    ss CP $CURRENT_SOURCE_SAFE_PROJECT
    ss project
}
quietsreset()
{
    ss CP $CURRENT_SOURCE_SAFE_PROJECT -O-
}


#----Commit *one file* -that is already added- to SS----#
sscommitone()
{

    FULLPATH=$1
    DIR=$(echo ${FULLPATH%/*})

    SS_COMMENT="$PROJECT - TGR: $TGR\n\n"

    #go to correct place in working directory 
    pushd $DIR  
    #checkout file without overwriting local copy
    #echo Y | ss checkout "$FULLPATH" -G-WR -Y$SSNAME
    ss checkout "$FULLPATH" -G-WR -Y$SSNAME -I-Y
    #check in the file with comment
    #echo Y | ss checkin "$1" -C"$SS_COMMENT" -W -Y$SSNAME  
    ss checkin "$1" -C"$SS_COMMENT" -W -Y$SSNAME -I-Y   
    #go back to the directoy we were in -root-
    popd

}
#----bulk commit---#
sscommit()
{
    for file in $1; do
        sscommitone $file
    done
}
#----bulk add-----#
AddEachNewFile()
{
    printf "\n\nAdding files requires us to loop, so we can add to the correct directory"

    for file in $1; do

    printf "\n--Resetting Dir---\n"
    quietsreset

    new_file=$(echo ${file##*/})
    directory=$(echo ${file%/*})


    #cp to folder
    echo "Directory is: $directory"
    quietsreset
    test=$(ss CP $directory 2>&1 | grep -c 'exist' 2>&1)


    if (( "1"== $test )); 
    then
    echo "Did not to find directory! It does not exist!....yet :)";

    new_directory=$directory;
    last_directory=$directory;
    while (( "1"== $test )); 
    do
        echo "->This parent directory does not exist, try going up";
        echo "---trying to cp to $new_directory"
        last_directory=$(echo ${new_directory})
        new_directory=$(echo ${new_directory%/*})

        quietsreset
        test=$(ss CP $new_directory 2>&1 | grep -c 'exist' 2>&1)

        echo "[+]"
    done

    echo "Directory does not exit, need to add $last_directory";
    ss Add $last_directory -R -C"$SS_COMMENT" -Y$SSNAME 

    else
    echo "Directory already exist, need to add file: ${file}";
    ss Add $file -C"$SS_COMMENT" -Y$SSNAME 
    fi 



    done

}

#use this function for when you forgot to fill in TGR info
ptgr()
{
    updateModDelAddVars $1
    printTGRInfo
}
#--- vars needed for to perform ss operations ----
updateModDelAddVars()
{
    #files to check out and in again from SS
    MODIFIED_FILES=$( git diff --name-only $1  --diff-filter=M) 
    #files to add to SS
    ADDED_FILES=$( git diff --name-only  $1  --diff-filter=A) 
    #file to delete from SS
    DELETED_FILES=$( git diff --name-only  $1  --diff-filter=D) 
}

printTGRInfo()
{
    printf "Please update the TGR with the following changed files:"
    printf " \n***********************\n"
    printf "|--Modified Files --\n\n"
    printf "$MODIFIED_FILES"
    printf " \n--\n"
    printf "|--New Files --\n\n"
    printf "$ADDED_FILES"
    printf " \n--\n"
    printf "|--Deleted Files --\n\n"
    printf "$DELETED_FILES"
    printf " \n\n ********************* \n"
}



##------Pull -todo- find out what other command is assigned to sspull!
sspullb()
{
    if [ ! -d ".git" ]; then
    echo "Must be ran from root git/ss rep"
    exit;
    fi

    #save branch we are on
    BRANCH=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD | sed -e 's,.*/\(.*\),\1,')



    #jump to "fake upstream"
    git checkout vss_branch

    #update vss branch to match vss..   
    echo "grabbing all files from sourcesafe"
    ssclone

    ##figure out files I have changed
    FILES=$( git diff --name-only master vss_branch) 

    ##grab the recent history for those files & everything else seperately  
    NOW=$(date)
    SSFILEHISTORY=$(ss History . $FILES -#3)
    SSHISTORY=$(ss History . -#3)

    ##now add & commit those files with a comment
    git add --all   
    MESSAGE=$(echo -e "Source safe sync: $NOW \n Changes to my files: \n $SSFILEHISTORY  \nChanges To Other Files:\n $SSHISTORY")
    git commit -a -m"$MESSAGE"


    #jump back to branch that wants to pull
    git checkout $BRANCH
    git pull    

}

##------ 'Push' 
sspush()
{
    if [ ! -d ".git" ]; then
    echo "Must be ran from root git/ss rep"
    exit;
    fi

    BRANCH=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD | sed -e 's,.*/\(.*\),\1,')

    ##-TODO- check for git error at checkout attempt instead!
    ##we might have some work uncommitted (naughty) 
    ##git stash

    #get a suitable amount of git master comments for SS comment SS comment IS limted to 500chars though...
    GIT_COMMENT=$(git log --pretty=format:"%h %s" --no-merges -n 3)
    git log --no-merges > fullGitHistory.githistory

    #figure out files that need to go into source safe
    updateModDelAddVars vss_branch

    #ok now make vss_branch up to date -this keeps git happy :)-
    #the odd syntax is due to the fact we are treating vss_branch as our upstream
    git push . HEAD:vss_branch


    #check the file in with latest git comments but keep files as writeable
    #--TODO-- read -p "Please enter the TGR this commit relates to: " TGR 
    TGR=$ACTIVE_TRACK_REF

    #Add each file (and possible directory)
    printf "\n---------------------------------------------------\n"
    printf "Adding new files \n->\n $ADDED_FILES"
    printf "\n---------------------------------------------------\n"
    SS_COMMENT="$PROJECT - TGR: $TGR  \n\n$GIT_COMMENT" 
    AddEachNewFile $ADDED_FILES

    printf "\n---------------------------------------------------\n"
    printf "Deleting old files \n->\n $DELETED_FILES"
    printf "\n---------------------------------------------------\n"
    ss Delete $DELETED_FILES -Y$SSNAME -I-N

    #Loop through the files, checking in and out from correct directory 
    printf "\n---------------------------------------------------\n"
    printf "Overwriting modified files \n->\n $MODIFIED_FILES"
    printf "\n---------------------------------------------------\n"    
    sscommit $MODIFIED_FILES

    #update git history file -this way SS has all the rich comment history I store with git despite SS's 500 comment character limit-
    ss Add fullGitHistory.githistory -C"Log of all git history"
    sscommitone fullGitHistory.githistory

    #now print the message needed for the TGR comment
    printTGRInfo


    #"unpop" all the things we just did to restore working tree
    git checkout $BRANCH

    ##--TODO-- check for git error at checkout attempt instead!
    ##git stash apply 



}

#replace Source-safe code with my master branch code
masterpushss()
{   
    echo "to master branch"
    git checkout master 
    sspush  
}
#merge master with source safe code
masterpullss()
{   
    git checkout master
    sspullb
}

#get master to perform pull and push 
synch()
{
    masterpullss
    masterpushss
}


##----True Diff---
hardrefupdate()
{
    REF_FOLDER="$CURRENT_PROJ_DIR$REF_APPEND"
    rm -rf $REF_FOLDER
    updateref

}
updateref()
{
    REF_FOLDER="$CURRENT_PROJ_DIR$REF_APPEND"
    if [ ! -d $REF_FOLDER ]; then     
        mkdir $REF_FOLDER
    fi
    pushd $REF_FOLDER
    ssclone
    popd

}

compare_toREF()
{

    if [ -z "$BEYOND_COMPARE_SESSION" ]; then
        bcompare $CURRENT_PROJ_DIR $REF_FOLDER /iu /filters="-*.scc;-*.opensdf;-*.sdf;-*.orig" /qc=size 
    else    
        bcompare $BEYOND_COMPARE_SESSION
    fi



}
#should only be needed for sanity checks -diff with vss_branch *should* achieve the same-
diffallss()
{
    if [ -z ${CURRENT_PROJ_DIR+x} ]; 
        then echo "CURRENT_PROJ_DIR is unset"; 
        exit;
    fi

    UpdateRef
    compare_toREF   
}
harddiffallss()
{
    if [ -z ${CURRENT_PROJ_DIR+x} ]; 
        then echo "CURRENT_PROJ_DIR is unset"; 
        exit;
    fi

    hardrefupdate
    compare_toREF   
}



#PS1='[\u@\h`__git_ps1` \W]\$
```

Comment: I will admit this has become more of a "is it possible" then a proper solution :p

Answer (score 3):

A couple of minor issues, from top to bottom.

---

When you need to embed double-quotes in a string, 
and you don't need to embed variables inside,
then it's easier to use single-quotes.
So instead of this:

> ```
> alias bcompare="START / \"C:\Program Files (x86)\Beyond Compare 3\BCompare.exe\""
> ```

This is easier:

```
alias bcompare='START / "C:\Program Files (x86)\Beyond Compare 3\BCompare.exe"'
```

---

No need to break out of the double-quotes here:

> ```
> alias ssclone="ss get "$CURRENT_SOURCE_SAFE_PROJECT" -W -R -Q -Y$SSNAME -I-N"
> ```

You could embed the variable simply:

```
alias ssclone="ss get $CURRENT_SOURCE_SAFE_PROJECT -W -R -Q -Y$SSNAME -I-N"
```

---

Regarding this piece:

> ```
> if [ -z ${CURRENT_SOURCE_SAFE_PROJECT+x} ];
> ```

...What the heck is `${CURRENT_SOURCE_SAFE_PROJECT+x}` ???
I'd appreciate if you could explain in comments :-)
Especially a keyword would be nice that I can search for in `man bash`.
I'd be really interested to know.

As it stands, it seem to me the expression will always evaluate to the letter "x",
which is not empty, so the `if` will always be false.

---

Unnecessary `;` at the end of some lines:

> ```
>     then echo "CURRENT_SOURCE_SAFE_PROJECT is unset"; 
>     exit;
> ```

Remove those.

---

In some `ss` commands you use `cp`, in others you use `CP`.
I suggest to be consistent and stick with the same style everywhere.

---

The `echo` in a subshell here is unnecessary:

> ```
> DIR=$(echo ${FULLPATH%/*})
> ```

This is better:

```
DIR=${FULLPATH%/*}
```

The same goes for these:

> ```
> new_file=$(echo ${file##*/})
> directory=$(echo ${file%/*})
> ```

---

In `AddEachNewFile` you have a for-loop with the body not well-indented:

> ```
> for file in $1; do
>
> printf "\n--Resetting Dir---\n"
> quietsreset
> ```

In the same method you also have an `if` block not well-indented.
I suggest to fix these, as they hurt readability and can easily lead to bugs.

---

No need to quote `exist` here:

> ```
> test=$(ss CP $directory 2>&1 | grep -c 'exist' 2>&1)
> ```

This is the same and simpler:

```
test=$(ss CP $directory 2>&1 | grep -c exist 2>&1)
```

---

The rest of the code has similar issues to the ones I already pointed out:

- bad indents
- unnecessary trailing `;`
- unnecessary quotes
- unnecessary `echo` subshells

Review the entire code, and follow the suggestions above.

When done, copy-paste your code on http://www.shellcheck.net/#,
and correct the remaining warnings it tells you.

Comment: Some great suggestions, thank you janos. I will read through and update accordingly. Regarding the updated code, should I just put it in an edit? 

As for the +x. I honestly for the life of me can't remember (comments ftw) so its either a typo or a bad attempt to check that the folder exists.

Comment: Hi @chrispepper1989, no, you shouldn't edit the code in your question, as that would invalidate my review. You can post a new question with the revised version for another round of reviews if you still need.

Comment: I was wondering new question or an ---Update--- to the question?

Comment: Don't wonder: new question is the way we do here. It's also better for you, more questions usually lead to more rep ;-)